# Puppeteer - Authorize device (2FA)

Tags: puppeteer, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

Is there a way to authorize Puppeteer for 2FA authentication?

Scenario:

1. Run Puppeteer and visit a 2FA protected URL
2. Enter credentials and wait for redirection
3. Request one-time passcode
4. Enter the passcode
5. Wait for redirection
6. Close the Puppeteer instance
7. Run Puppeteer and visit a 2FA protected URL
8. The protected page should be loaded not asking for the passcode anymore

This scenario doesn't work in my case :(

Any other library that can go successfully through this scenario?

Comment: There are a lot of steps in the scenario :) any particular difficulty you're facing?

Comment: Yes, whenever I run the script I will be asked to "authorize the device" issuing one-time passcode regardless of that I already passed this step once...

Comment: Then you should edit your question and ask about *that* in detail. Do you save the browsing state between steps 6 and 7 somehow?

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible scenarios to handle 2FA using puppeteer, depending on the nature of the situation (it's not entirely clear from the way you phrase the question).

1. Replicating session data (in this scenario, you can't have someone provide you the code the second time, you need to bypass it in the future altogether):

I'm going to assume the site you are dealing with is performing some sort of analysis on the browser to determine whether to prompt for a 2FA code or not. In my experience, sometimes there is a random element to this that you can't control, but replicating the exact browser state (user data, cookies, everything) is a start. Pair that with a consistent IP address that has answered correctly previously, and I think chances are very very good.

See my [code](https://github.com/dcubasoy/puppeteer-theater/blob/master/classes/puppeteer-bot-2a.js) here, or if that is too heavy, here is a simple implementation of the functions I'm using to save the session data: [simple code](https://gist.github.com/nicoandmee/e6f9a0b839f713c53ac1674537195537). In short, I'm converting the session data, cookies- everything that distinguishes that instance of chromium and stuffing it into a base64 string, then later I simply load that data and assume the exact state the browser had previously. I'm pretty sure this is what you want.

2. Interactive Bot

I'm unsure if this applies to your use-case, but I faced a situation where I needed to pull 2FA codes from a user's phone/email in real-time while the puppeteer was in the middle of performing a login process. The browser could not re-launch because the 2FA code would no longer be valid. It's not a trivial problem. I ended up using Redis and built a framework [puppeteer-theater](https://github.com/dcubasoy/puppeteer-theater) that addressed this use-case among pretty much every scraping/automation workflow I have encountered.

Feel free to reach out if you are looking for specific help.

Comment: Nico, thank you for the very detailed elaboration. I am dealing with almost 3000 internal web pages and most of them have their own specifics... However, I've solved my basic issue (not keeping the browser authorized) switching to "selenium-webdriver""- it worked out-of-the-box. Thank you one more time...

Comment: Hey @Nico i'm afraid the links in your first answer are 404ing now .. was really looking forward to them too :)

Comment: Just looked around a bit and found the new locations for the two URLs in the answer above

Comment: There are also other pieces of code and guides out there, if you look hard enough eg: https://gist.github.com/jeroenvisser101/636030fe66ea929b63a33f5cb3a711ad

This came from searching for "restoring session including cookies puppeeteer"